# How to search data from combined column? yajra, laravel5

Tags: sql, laravel, datatable

i have issue that i cant find data from combined column
i have datatables like this, the name is combined from users.first_name and users.last_name but it cant be find by that fullname
example:
first_name: Ana, 
last_name: Queen 
if i search "Ana" it will result all with first name Ana
but if i search "Ana Queen", im not get the result.

```
$(function () {
    $("#datatable").DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        ajax: "{!! route('admin.customers.getdata','Umum') !!}",
        columns: [
            { data: null, bSortable: false, className: "text-center" },
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "name", name: "name" },
            { data: "type" },
            { data: "email" },
            { data: "location" },
            { data: "active", bSortable: false, className: "text-center" },
            { data: "free_ongkir", bSortable: false, className: "text-center" },
            { data: "action", bSortable: false, className: "text-center" }
        ],
        fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
            $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
            return nRow;
        }
    });
```

this is the code from controller

```
public function getdata($type)
{
    $users = User::where(['type'=>$type])->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('slug', '=', 'user');
    })->get();
    foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
        if($value->id == Sentinel::getUser()->id) $value->disabled = "disabled";
        else$value->disabled = "";
    }
    return Datatables::of($users)
    ->editColumn('name', '
        <a href="{{ route(\'admin.customers.show\', $id) }}">{!! $first_name." ".$last_name !!}</a>
    ')
    ->filterColumn('name', function($query, $keyword) {
                $sql = "CONCAT(users.first_name,'-',users.last_name)  like ?";
                $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$keyword}%"]);
            })
    ->editColumn('type', function($users) {
        if($users->hasAccess('superadmin')) return 'Super Admin';
        else return "Komoditi $users->type";
    })
    ->editColumn('active', function($users) {
        if(!$users->is_approved) {
            return '<span class="has-error form-group"><label><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Belum di approve</label></span>';
        } else if(Activation::completed($users)) {
            return '<span class="has-success form-group"><label><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Aktif</label></span>';
        } else {
            return '<span class="has-error form-group"><label><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> Belum Aktivasi</label></span>';
        }
    })
    ->editColumn('free_ongkir', function($users) {
      if ($users->free_ongkir == 1) {
        return '<span class="has-success form-group"><label><i class="fa fa-check"></i></label></span>';
      }else {
        return '<span class="has-error form-group"><label><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></label></span>';
      }
    })
    ->editColumn('location', function($users){
        if(empty($users->city->name)) return 'None';
        else return $users->city->name;
    })
    ->addColumn('action', '@if(Sentinel::getUser()->hasAccess(["customers.edit"]))<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="location.href=\'{{ route(\'admin.customers.edit\', $id) }}\'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
        @endif
        {!! Form::open([
            \'method\'=>\'DELETE\',
            \'route\' => [\'admin.customers.destroy\', $id],
            \'style\' => \'display:inline\'
        ]) !!}
        @if(Sentinel::getUser()->hasAccess(["customers.destroy"]))
            {!! Form::button(\'<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>\', [\'class\' => \'btn btn-danger btn-md\',\'type\'=>\'submit\',\'onclick\'=>\'return confirm("Are you sure want to delete?")\', $disabled]) !!}
         @endif
        {!! Form::close() !!}

    ')
    ->make(true);
}
```

How to combined first_name and last_name column and i can search base on that.
Thankyou.

Comment: instead of combine two column split you name explode(" ",$name) and search both same time

Comment: where i put that? sorry im new to this T.T

Comment: so your query solve or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
 $datatables->filterColumn('name', 'whereRaw', 
 "CONCAT(users.fname,',',users.lname) like ? ", ["%$keyword%"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example with MySql DB.

```
$query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", first_name, last_name)'), 'like', $search);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `=` to . "%" . `like` . "%". Like so:

```
$users = User::where(['type'=>$type])->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('slug', '%' .'like'. '%', 'user');
```